# game not detecting any nearby gyms or pokestops in my area

Tags: pokemon-go

I have been playing pokemon go for about a week now and the game worked perfectly all this time. But recently when I logged in, the game fails to detect any of the nearby gyms or pokestops. There are'nt any nearby pokemon shown in the box below as well.There are like 2 pokestops and 3 gyms in my area but the game is not detecting any of them for a couple of days now.

Comment: Close game. Reopen game. Hope for the best.

Comment: i did that. but that did'nt seem to fix the issue. I even uninstalled and reinstalled the game. but that too did not  work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which country are you playing in? The game has stopped loading Pokestops and Gyms for several people playing in the South Asia (India, Nepal, etc).

This might be happening because they no longer want unofficial regions to be able to play Pokemon Go.

Comment: r u sure?
cuz iam in india now.

Comment: This is pure speculation.  There is no proof at all.

Answer (score 1):

I find that when I open the game it will most the map first and then populate it with gyms and pokestops. I'm guessing you gave it time to load (could take several minutes with a weak connection), but I would double check your data and Wi-Fi connections. If either is weak, turn it off as it may be causing your game to slow down as it tries to use the service but cannot receive enough information.

If I load the game in Wi-Fi and walk out of range before the game has loaded, it will get stuck at a loading screen indefinitely and I will have to do a full close and restart.

Answer (score 0):

Its server issues. The reason for this server issue now is its launching in Japan.